# Keep the images downloaded in the listview during scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-arrayadapter

I'm developing my first app and have been reading a LOT here.

I've been trying to find a solution for the following issue for over a week with no luck.
I have an `Adapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter` to show image and 3 lines of text in each row.
Inside the `getView` I assign relevant information for the `TextView`s and use `ImageLoader` class to download image and assign it to the `ImageView`.

Everything works great! I have 4.5 rows visible on my screen (out of total of 20). When I scroll down for the first time the images continue to download and be assigned in right order to the list.

BUT when I scroll back the list looses all the images and start redrawing them again (0.5-1 sec per image) in correct order. From what I've been reading it's the standard list performance but I want to change it.

I want that, once the image was downloaded, it will be "sticked" to the list for the whole session of the current window. Just like in Contacts list or in the Market. It is only 20 images (6-9kb each).

Hope I managed to explain myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cache each image after download it, and each time the adapter need it check if its already downloaded get it from cache (disk or memory) otherwise download it.

at first i recommended you to read this tutorial from android dev site http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

or use an external lib like this one https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: Thanks a lot! I looked through the dev site and downloaded their example to try to understand my mistake but it's above my current development skills (like I mentioned, I'm developing my first app - I didn't mention that I have no previous java experience). So I ended up with using the external lib you gave me. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the ArrayAdapter is reusing the list view rows as you scroll, so as you scroll down, the top row will be reused and inserted at the bottom of the list (for performance reasons).

Your best bet here is to try to cache the images locally on your device to avoid calling the ImageLoader every time.

One pretty good library that solves this problem is ignition. It's open source and available here: https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition

Take a look at `RemoteImageView` for a good example of the caching mechanism.

Comment: Thanks but like I said in the reply to the above solution, it's still pretty hard for me to understand the different caching mechanisms.. So after several minutes of trying to understand the `RemoteImageView` class you proposed, I gave up for now - I will come back to learn this issue better but not at this point.